# Matlab NE Builder "Access Violation"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matlab

I'm using deploytool to create a Matlab class (MLTestClass) with a method (makeSqr) as shown in [this MathWorks tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/using-matlab-builder-ne-68758.html).  After importing the relevant libraries in Visual Studio 2012, the line `MLTestClass obj = new MLTestClass();` causes the program to crash with an "Access Violation."  I'm using MCR v8.1.  I've seen somewhere that this can be caused by compiling the .m file with the wrong compiler, but the only compiler I have on my computer (according to `mbuild -setup`) is "Microsoft Visual C++ 2012" (although I'm compiling for use in a C# project, if that makes a difference).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps this is a 32/64-bit issue? Did you compile from 64-bit MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, I compiled from 64-bit Matlab 2013a.  Is there a way to compile so that it's compatible with Visual Studio?  (From what I can tell, there's no 64-bit version of VS, but please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: I tried installing 32-bit Matlab and using the deploytool from there, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the builder to use .net framework 3.5 instead of 4.0 and make sure that the application that wants to use it also based on the same framework.